# Creating a window without a caption

Tags: winapi

I am calling CreateWindowExW like this (simplified):

```
CreateWindowExW(0, "classname", 0, WS_DLGFRAME, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

After the window is created, it has WS_BORDER, WS_CAPTION and a few other styles that I didn't give it. According to the MSDN docs, WS_DLGFRAME shouldn't have a caption, so why is WS_CAPTION being added? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is it your own window class or are you re-using one.  It's possible for the window to be mucking with its own styles after you create it.

Comment: I'm using a custom window class that I created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a caption bar or border?  Use WS_POPUP

Comment: It seems that when WS_POPUP is specified along with other window styles it prevents Windows from adding other unwanted styles. I must have missed that in the docs, thanks!